# Completely New / Independent user on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Is there a way to setup a completely new and independent windows user meaning no files or installed applications are shared across.

I've tried creating a new user but all browser settings and installed apps such as NordVPN are still installed. I don't want to remove them from each user (that'd be no good) id want to install them separately depending on the new user.

Is this possible?

Comment: A user will have access to any applications installed for all users.  There is no way to get around that fact.

Comment: Ah okay thank you